# Call main window from the pop up window

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2

I have pop up window and after doing something in the pop up, I want to return to main window. now instead, the form which should appear on the main window appears in my pop up window.

```
function checkForm() {
//check all necessary things
var varAmount =....; //which will get after process insides javascript
window.location = 'myaction.action?amount='+varAmount ;
}

<form name="frmUpload" target="main">...
<input type="button" class="button" value="Save" onclick="checkForm();"/>
</form>
```

I want to **pass the Amount value to my action** too and want to **return back to the main window**(and close the pop up window after the process is done and call myaction.actoin).

Although I call `target="main"`, it doesn't go close the pop up and return to main.

Comment: use iframe and make an target to that while uploading

Comment: `window.opener` in pop-up will refer to the window, which opened it, or your main window.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to target the form to the main window you need to name the main window in a script IN the main window:

`window.name="main";`

Then change the button to submit and EITHER remove the javascript or move the checking to the onsubmit

```
function checkForm() {
//check all necessary things
var varAmount =....; //which will get after process insides javascript
  if (...) return false; // cancel submit
  return true; // allow submit
}


<form name="frmUpload" target="main" onsubmit="return checkForm(this)">...
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Save" />
</form>
```

If you need the javascript and the button where it is, you need to change it to

```
function checkForm() {
  //check all necessary things
  var varAmount =....; //which will get after process insides javascript
  window.opener.location = 'myaction.action?amount='+varAmount
  // OR using the name of the opener window
  //window.open('myaction.action?amount='+varAmount,"main");
}
```